# Indexing SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, indexing

i got questions about indexing SQL database:

1. Is it better to index boolean column or rather not because there are only 2 options? i know if the table is small then indexing will not change anything, but im asking about table with 1mln records.
2. If i got two dates ValidFrom and ValidTo is it better to create 1 index with 2 columns or 2 seperate indexes? In 90% of queries i use where validfrom < date && validto > date, but there are also few selects only with validfrom or only with validto
3. whats the diffrence between clustered and non-clistered index? i cant find any article, so a link would be great

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You both tagged MySQL and SQL-server. This answer is MySQL inspired.

1. It depends on many things, but more important than the size is the variation. If about 50% of the values are TRUE, that means the rest of the values (also about 50%) are FALSE and an index will not help much. If only 2% of the values are TRUE and your queries often only need TRUE records, this index [will be useful](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)!
2. If your queries often use both, put both in the index. If one is used more than the other, put that one FIRST in the index, so the composite index can be used for the one field as well.
3. A [clustered index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html) means that the data actually is inside the index. A non-clustered index just points to the data, which is actually stored elsewhere. The PRIMARY KEY in InnoDB is a clustered index.

If you want to use Indexes in MySQL, [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) is your friend!

Comment: well im using postgresql :P but also mssql and mysql, are there any diffrence between those database in indexing? i mean im not asking how the indexing are working in the core of servers, but for user? boolean will work diffrently in every sql engine? but thanks with answers, ill get more with true than false like 80% to 20%, so thanks ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is all for SQL Server, which is what I know about...

1 - Depends on cardinality, but as a rule an index on a single boolean field (`BIT` in SQL Server) won't be used since it's not very selective.

2 - Make 2 indexes, one with both, and the other with just the second field from the first index.  Then you are covered in both cases.

3 - Clustered indexes contain the data for ALL fields at the leaf level (the entire table basically) ordered by your clustered index field.  Non-clustered indexes contain only the key fields and any `INCLUDE`d fields at the leaf level, with a pointer to the clustered index row if you need any other data from other fields for that row.

Comment: If you make an index on `(A,B)` and do a `SELECT ... WHERE A`, SQL server can't use that index? MySQL can!

Comment: No, it can.  But if you do a `SELECT...WHERE B` it won't use it if `A` isn't in the filter.

Comment: ok i understand this with (A,B) but how sql checks ValidFrom < date when there is index with 2 columns? i just try to understand how it works ;) are indexes working when there is no == but < or >?

Comment: @Cfaniak - Think of the index like a phone book.  If you know a last name, you can find the first name too because the phone book is in order of Last Name, First Name. Without a last name, you can't find everyone named "Joe" because of the field order.

Comment: i understand index (A,B), but cant understand date index yet, but its another story, is SQL server using just best index? i mean if i got index(A,B) and index(B) when i searching a and b is index(B) still used or just index(a,b)? i hope only index(A,B) ;)

Comment: Probably only index(A,B).  There are exceptions (for instance if the ordering of the indexes is different, or if A is a very very large field which bloats the size of the index).

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use the "Filtered Index", the number of records up to 2 million with no problems.
2. Create 1 Non clustered index instead of 2 Filtered Index
3. Different in user experience, these two aspects are not related to each other nothing. The search index (PK: Primary Key) is different than searching for a range of values ​​(Non clustered Index often used in tracing the value range), in fact finding by PK represented less than 1% queries